# Android ActivityGroup Menu Problem

Tags: android, menu, android-activity

I have one problem using `ActivityGroup`. I have two activities inside an `ActivityGroup` and both of them use a menu (overriding the onCreateOptionMenu and onOptionsItemSelected).

Well, the problem is that the second activity in the group doesn't show the menu when I press the menu Key. The first activity works fine showing the menu.

Any idea about this issue?

I have this code in child activity:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, MENU_REFRESH, 0, R.string.menu_refresh).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_refresh);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_REFRESH:
        Log.d(TAG,"REFRESH");
        refresh();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I think this is amazing behavior of second activity. Try to select any control at present on 2nd activity and then press menu button. Menu will appear, but I dont know why.

Comment: I'm having the same problem i'm getting the same menu for second activity also. even i have a separate menu define for second activity. please let me know how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1ca86fd9a5497de2?pli=1) thread.

> Menu's can be handled in the parent
>   aactivity, but created in the child
>   activity

Comment: ok but how can i invoke a method of the child activity if i handle the menu in the parent activity?

Comment: @xger86x: That's the issue. You should handle the menu in a child activity not in the parent one.

Comment: @macarse ok so.... how do i do that? do you understand my question? If  i have to invoke a method on the child activity i can't from the parent..

Comment: @xger86x: What I understand is that you are placing the menu code on the parent when you should place it on the child. If this is not the case, please provide some code so it would be easier to help you. Thanks.

Comment: i have added the code in the question. If i put the onCreateOptionMenu in parent activity, onOptionItemSelected is not invoked in child activity

Comment: @xger86x: Cool, I guess I understand now. Place the `onCreateOptionMenu` in the child and the `onOptionItemSelected` in the parent. And I guess you can use `LocalActivityManager` to call a method from an specific activity. Try it out!

Comment: it works placing onCreateOptionMenu in parent activity and onOptionItemSelected on child activity and using localactivitymanager to invoke the method onOptionItemSelected.

Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

Another nice way of handling this is by using the ActivityGroup's LocalActivityManager.  Get the local activity manager, get the current activity, and perform that activity's appropriate method:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()
        .onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()
        .onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    //super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()
        .onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

Note: using this strategy, you must not call super.onCreateOptionsMenu from the child activity- doing so causes a stack overflow exception.  I'm not sure what the purpose of calling the superclass's on* methods, as I've omitted them and have seen no negative results. (... yet)

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the menu methods in the activity group, and call the corresponding methods on the child activity.  See this article: [How to Create Options Menu on Child Activity inside an ActivityGroup](http://www.londatiga.net/it/android-coding-tips-how-to-create-options-menu-on-child-activity-inside-an-activitygroup/)

```
public class TestGroup extends ActivityGroup {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //start child activity
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code on the tabGroupActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return  getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

use the code which given below in both 2 child Activities

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_1, menu);
    return true;
}// menu_1 is the xml file in menu folder
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.weekly:
        Intent weekly = new Intent(getParent(),Activity1.class);
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("weeklyview", weekly);

        break;

    case R.id.daily :
        Intent daily = new Intent(getParent(),Activity2.class);
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity2 = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
        parentActivity2.startChildActivity("daily", daily);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    //use return true
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to create the menu in the ActivityGroup root and then use    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) to clear and re-add menu items.

In ActivityGroup class:

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
> {
>     //what is the current activity?
>     menu.add(0, 0, 0, "holder");
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
> {
>     //start a new
>     menu.clear();
>     //add some menu options
>     .getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
>     return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
> }
> ```

In Activity:

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
> { //add menus or inflate here
>     return true;
> }
> ```