# activitygroup and currentactivity

Tags: android

I am having trouble with menus and activitygroups. I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157406/android-activitygroup-menu-problem) and the issue I'm still having is that when I press back the currentactivity still seems to be the activity i just came back from, so the activitygroup is returning false for the menu when I press menu for the 1st activity, so its menu is no longer created. this is my group's back method:

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         if (this.getCurrentActivity() instanceof mpVoucherDetailsPage  || 
                 this.getCurrentActivity() instanceof MyVoucherDetailsPage){
            MapVouchers.theMap.enableLocationOverlay();
         }
         MapGroup.group.back();
   }
```

This is my group's menu methods:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       System.out.println("onprepareoptionsmenu group called.");
       System.out.println( getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu) );
       System.out.println(getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().getClass());
       return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
```

Is there any way to make it return the current view's menu instead of the currentactivity's(which the user no longer sees)?

Comment: `ActivityGroup` has been deprecated, so I recommend you start considering how to rework your application to avoid them, either using simple views or using fragments and the Android Compatibility Library.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please suggest best way as alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the activity group described on this page:

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html