# Contextmenu in Activity Group

Tags: android, contextmenu, activitygroup

i am using a Activity Group for a tab group.

one of the child Activity in a tab group Activity contains a Contextmenu. but when i click on the menu item, the code which written under the context menu item selected didn't run.

```
the code which i was written in tabgroup Activity is given below

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

the code which i was written in child Achtivity is given below

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if(v.getId()==R.id.appointment_listview1)
    {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
                (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;


        appointmnt_row item = (appointmnt_row)appListView.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(dateString);
        menu.add(0, item.getId(), 0, "Delete");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getTitle()=="Delete")
    {Log.e("delete",""+item1.getId());
            } return true;}
```

pls help me

Comment: show onContextItemSelected method

Comment: thanks for your interaction. i think the main problem is that i am using the Activity group so implementing the context menu in child activity is the problem

Comment: Have you try? getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onContextItemSelected(item) in onContextItemSelected. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157406/android-activitygroup-menu-problem

Comment: yaa i use the getLocatActivityManager().getCurrentActivity.onContextItemSelected(item). i use this code on AcitivityGroup

Comment: i use this god successfully in my Default Activity(not a child Activity).. but i cant this code in a child Activity

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("YourActivity", new
                                            Intent(this,YourActivity.class)
                                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                                            .getDecorView();

          ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list); // find your view,for example list.
          list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    Log.v(null, "ITEM CREATED");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "1 item");
    getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.v(null, "ITEM SELECTED");
    return getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity().onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Its works for me

Comment: in my child Activity i cant call the function getLocalActivityManager()

Comment: That code shoud be added in activityGroup class.                   Just call findViewById and set Listener in child activity

Comment: can you share your groupActivity and the child Activity pls...

ikky.ragav.exe@gmail.com